# Libgdx specifying font size for scrolling dynamic list entries

Tags: fonts, libgdx, scrollpane

I want to create a scrolling dynamic list which contains clickable entries.  My problem is
the font size of the entries.  The font is too small.  Do I have to create a separate skin to use just for this or is there some way I can scale the existing font up.  I am currently using the unaltered uiskin.  Here is my code.  I am able to add list entries and they are all clickable (listener code not included here) but the text is just too small when displayed.

```
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    shotArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    shotList = new List(shotArrayList.toArray(),skin);
    ScrollPane scrollPane2 = new ScrollPane(shotList, skin);
    table.add(scrollPane2).width(w*0.7f).height(h*0.3f);
```

I only put the scrollpane in a table cell for helping with placing on the stage with other actors.  I don't think it's really affecting my font size problem.  This method of creating a dynamic scrolling list does work nicely but I am open to better solutions.

My problem is just the font size. I have tried using an ArrayList of Labels because I can apply a scale to a Label but when I converted the ArrayList to array then my entries all simply said "Label".  I hope I have explained my problem and eagerly await a solution.

Answer (score 3):

In the uiskin.json file you'll find lines that specify the font such as:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } }
```

You can specify whatever font you like here and reference it elsewhere in the file using the font name 'default-font'. You'll need to pre-generate the font at the required size using a bitmap font generator such as [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/).

You can export your font from BMFont and add it into your assets folder.

A second option is to scale the font already used in the skin, although fonts never look good scaled up. You can use the following to double the font size, assuming 'default-font' is the name of your font.

```
skin.getFont("default-font").scale(2);
```

You can improve the scaling slightly by turning on linear filtering for the font.

```
skin.getFont("default-font").getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

So your final code would look like this

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
skin.getFont("default-font").scale(2);
skin.getFont("default-font").getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
shotArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
shotList = new List(shotArrayList.toArray(),skin);
ScrollPane scrollPane2 = new ScrollPane(shotList, skin);
table.add(scrollPane2).width(w*0.7f).height(h*0.3f);
```

If you want to get on to more advanced font scaling techniques then you may be interested in [distance field fonts](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts).